# how to incude logo in contcat form 7 email

Tags: plugins, email

I am using contact form 7 plugin. how to include logo in emails sending to user and admin.
I am new in word press.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own logo to the message like this.

1. Check "Use HTML content type" box in the Mail or Mail (2) section.
2. Place `<img src="{URL of the logo}" />` tag into the Message body textarea.

Comment: Barett: when i add this "<img src="{URL of the logo}" />" to message body then the emails are not sending

Comment: Are you replacing `{URL of the logo}` with the actual URL of the logo?

Comment: possible to send custom image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send the logo in hearer of the contact form 7 mail do the following step

1) You need to create html for your mail with header

2) Click on the "Use HTML content type" checkbox so it will add the HTML type in header it and send the HTML mail.

Enjoy,,

Comment: Sorry @Mitul, I didn't refresh the page before I posted my answered.

Comment: @JamesBarrett No problem

Comment: @Mitul It's not working instead of selecting that "Use HTML content type"